# Events and IPCServerChannel throws TargetInvocationException

Tags: c#, events, remoting, ipc

For some bizarre problem when I try to use Events and IPC Remoting am getting these exceptions, which would be the point? Has anyone had this problem?

### Client

```
BinaryClientFormatterSinkProvider clientProvider = new BinaryClientFormatterSinkProvider();

IDictionary prop = new Hashtable();
prop["name"] = "remote";
prop["secure"] = true;
prop["priority"] = 1;
prop["tokenImpersonationLevel"] = TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;

IpcClientChannel clientChannel = new IpcClientChannel(prop, clientProvider);
ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(clientChannel, true);
RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownClientType(typeof(Connector), "ipc://connector/connector");

Connector c = new Connector();
c.OnX += new Connector.X(c_OnX);
c.Connect();
```

### Server

```
BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider serverProvider = new BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider();
serverProvider.TypeFilterLevel = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.TypeFilterLevel.Full;

IDictionary prop = new Hashtable();
prop["name"] = "remote";
prop["secure"] = true;
prop["priority"] = 1;
prop["portName"] = "connector";
prop["tokenImpersonationLevel"] = TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
prop["authorizedGroup"] = new SecurityIdentifier("S-1-1-0").Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).ToString(); /* Everyone or Todos =p  - Sou amador, e dai ? */

// Create and register an IPC channel
IpcServerChannel serverChannel = new IpcServerChannel(prop, serverProvider);
ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(serverChannel, true);

// Expose an object
RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(typeof(Connector), "connector", WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);
```

### Exception

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled
  Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
    Server stack trace: 
       at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._SerializationInvoke(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, SignatureStruct& declaringTypeSig, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.CompleteISerializableObject(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.FixupSpecialObject(ObjectHolder holder)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups()
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CoreChannel.DeserializeBinaryRequestMessage(String objectUri, Stream inputStream, Boolean bStrictBinding, TypeFilterLevel securityLevel)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.BinaryServerFormatterSink.ProcessMessage(IServerChannelSinkStack sinkStack, IMessage requestMsg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream, IMessage& responseMsg, ITransportHeaders& responseHeaders, Stream& responseStream)
    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
       at Vex_Connector_Service.Connector.add_OnX(X value)
       at Vex_Connector_Client.Program.Main() in C:\Users\Vex\Desktop\Final Vex Connector\Vex Connector\Vex Connector Client\Program.cs:line 37
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
       Message=Could not load file or assembly 'Vex Connector Client, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado.
       Source=mscorlib
       FileName=Vex Connector Client, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
       FusionLog=WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

       StackTrace:
            at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
            at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
            at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
            at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
            at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
            at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.LoadAssemblyFromString(String assemblyName)
            at System.Reflection.MemberInfoSerializationHolder..ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
       InnerException:
```

Comment: unless you're stuck at .NET 2.0 or below, you shouldn't be using Remoting. It has been deprecated in favor of WCF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could not load file or assembly 'Vex Connector Client,...'

Pretty standard kind of error for a Remoting app, it just can't find the assembly.  Make sure it's there, preferably in the same directory as the exe.  Use Fuslogvw.exe if you have trouble diagnosing the reason it cannot find the assembly.

---

The fuslogvw traces show the problem clearly.  The server is looking for "vex connector client.exe" in its own directory, Final Vex Connector/Vex Connector/Vex Connector Service/
bin/Debug/.  But the file isn't there, it is stored in Final Vex Connector/Vex Connector/Vex Connector Client/bin/Debug/

Copy the file to fix the problem.

If you find it distasteful that the server needs the client.exe then put the classes they share in a separate project.

Comment: I could not find any problem in this program. I have two different applications: a client and a server. Does the server compilation depends on the client too? Do I need a circular dependency dealing with events? How do I configure Visual Studio for that?

Comment: It is a deployment problem.  Whatever assembly contains the Connector class needs to be present in both the server and the client directories.  Since the class is used in both.  You might want to put it in its own assembly.

Comment: Why I have that problem just when events are called? Methods run normally. I agreed, thats a deployment problem, but are in the Connector class?

Comment: Post the fuslogvw.exe trace if you can't sort it out.

Comment: There are no failed binds logged in that one.  No sign of any binds for the server.

Comment: Right! This time the server too. http://www.hlegius.pro.br/2010-01-06-Connector-fusloggvw-v2.zip